# Using jq to assign property of child to parent dictionary

Tags: javascript, json, jq

I have a TopoJSON file with several geometries. It looks like so:

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "objects": {
    "delegaciones": {
      "geometries": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "name": "Tlalpan",
            "municip": "012",
            "id": "09012",
            "state": "09"
          }
...
```

I want to be able to take the `id` field from `properties`, and assign it to the parent, so that the result is:

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "objects": {
    "delegaciones": {
      "geometries": [
        {
          "id": "09012",
          "properties": {
            "name": "Tlalpan",
            "municip": "012",
            "id": "09012", // <-- It's okay if it's removed or not
            "state": "09"
          }
...
```

I tried the following assignment on jq, but it's not correct:

```
jq '.objects.delegaciones.geometries[].id = .objects.delegaciones.geometries[].properties.id' topo_df.json
```

Anyone know how I can make jq iterate elements one by one? Or how I can make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following adds the "id" property as requested:

```
.objects.delegaciones.geometries[] |= (.id = .properties.id)
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought you could assign something inside an assignment itself. Interesting!